# <code> tag backgournd colour not filling element

Tags: html, css

I have a code tag containing some rendered JSON and a background-color applied.[image]

The html is just a simple < code> tag containing this, and my CSS for it is:

```
border: 1px solid #efeffe;
background-color: #6a6a6a;
white-space: pre;
color: white;
```

Any idea how to get a full background without just targeting text? Using Chrome.

Comment: I would wrap it with <div> and style that div with background and border.

Comment: It would work but for semantics and accessibility I wanted to know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 2):

The code tag is an inline element, meaning styling applied to it usually only affects the text itself. You could transform it to a block by adding `display: block;` to the style declaration.

Comment: I just posted that :) but I'll mark it accepted when I can - unless you just saw me post... ;)

Answer (score 1):

`code` is an inline element.  Inline elements will always show their background this way.  You could make it "block", but I wouldn't advise it.  You could do what stack overflow does in your very question with your sample code.  Wrape the `<code>` elements in `<pre>` tags.  Pre are block level elements and then you will show your background the way you want.

```
Write click and inspect this example to see how its done.
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised by comparnig it to < pre> that the issue was that this was an 'inline' element and it needed to be block:

```
display: block;
```